# Why do I get index error I try to multiply an element of a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, cs50

I am new to Python and don't really understand how lists differ from arrays. Upon searching, they are defined as dynamic arrays. I am unable to understand why I get IndexError when I try multiplying elements of list like array as in the third last line of code below. What restrictions do I face if I try to manipulate a list like an array? Here I have shared a part of my code.
Thanks in advance :)

```
import cs50

def main():
    credit = cs50.get_string("Number: ")
    while(int(credit) < 0):
        credit = cs50.get_string("Number: ")
    if int(credit) < 1000000000000 or int(credit) > 9999999999999999:
        print("INVALID")
        quit()


    cred = credit.split()
    n = len(credit)
    cred.pop()
    cred.reverse()

    i = 0
    
    while i < n:
        
        cred[i] = (int(cred[i]) % 10) + (int(cred[i]) // 10)
        i += 2
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cred.pop()
```

It makes the list an empty list if it contains only one element